# How to use Executor when there are thousands/dynamic number of tasks?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor, executor

I just found out about Java's Executor and I'm thinking whether it fits my needs. I have a database, to which tasks are constantly added.

1. I SQL SELECT all rows(tasks) from the database. At any time, there could be 100000, 200, 3 or 0 of them.
2. I see all examples are like this:

   ```
   ExecutorService taskExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);
   while(...) {
       taskExecutor.execute(new MyTask());
   }
   ```

   How could it be adjusted to my scenario? I can't just instantiate 100000 of MyTask's, it will waste a ton of memory.
3. How should I wait for finish and check again? I can't just wait until 100000 tasks are finished, because first one might finish in 5 secs and will stay unused for a long time until last one is finished, so we will be wasting time.

Comment: Why are you querying all the tasks from the database at the same time? Instead you should just query for as many tasks as you have capacity to work on (which may only be one) and then query again once the work is done and you have more capacity.

Answer (score 3):

An elegant and efficient way to do this would be to use a `BoundedExecutor` implementation as illustrated within the book Java Concurrency In Practice by Brian Goetz ([Github link here](https://github.com/benelog/java-concurrency/blob/master/src/main/java/net/jcip/examples/BoundedExecutor.java)).

The implementation provided on the Github link while a good starting point would also need to  make a few changes

1. In case you want to access the return values for the task then make
   sure that your tasks implement the [Callable interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) instead
   of `Runnable`.
2. Using an [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) instead of an `Executor` would be more
   beneficial since it helps us expose more granular shutdown
   functionality.
3. Expose set of methods that allow the executor to be shutdown by
   cleanly. These shutdown call implementations can simply delegate to
   the underlying `ExecutorService.shutdown()` or
   `ExecutorService.shutdownNow()` based on the requirement.

Also it would be good to keep the bound as a configuration parameter - this way when the bounded executor is initialized the number of tasks that can be executed safely in parallel is read off this configuration parameter.

This configuration parameter can be tuned based on your performance and scale testing to identify the optimal bound for your application without degrading it's performance or the underlying system performance.

Hope this helps.